# Sorting Div's in a grid

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, microsoft-metro

I wrote a JQuery plugin that simulates a Windows 8 metro style panorama on the web, allowing users to mouse-swype between panels in the panorama.

I want the content owner to be able to create tiles of different sizes for the panorama in a SharePoint list, where they can set certain parameters.

What I'm having trouble with is when the tiles go to be rendered, if some are single width and double height, I'm going to end up with a lot of empty spaces if they aren't created in a specific order.

I'd like the be able to have a 2x3 grid, where the content owner can choose between a 1x1 and 2x1 tile size, but have the rendered grid contain no empty spaces.

Help!

Comment: Would this help? -- http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It looks promising, thanks! Repost that in an answer and if it works well, we can use it and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/ -- it's a jQuery plugin to automatically tile DIVs in a manner similar to what you're trying to do.